# How can I mark a message as new in Alpine?

Tags: email, email-client, alpine-mail

While looking at a list of emails in Alpine, I inadvertently entered a message I wished to save for later reading. The "N" marking the message as new disappeared, of course. I'd like to mark it new again, so it stands out later when I have time to read it. However, I can't find any way to do this in the menus, help, or via a web search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type * then type n. This can do the job.